# Match prompt input with an array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am playing with some basic js I am just beginning to learn, so far I have the code below. I am trying to ask the user what their name is and then tell them if they share the same name as a racing driver (from my array **driversNames**).

If they have the same name as a racing driver it would tell them they do, if not it would tell them they don't. However I have a feeling I have something wrong here: **if (yourName === driversNames)** but I cannot figure it out.

It doesn't matter what I enter into the prompt, it always says sorry you don't have the same name.

```
var driversNames = ["Lewis", "Fernando", "Sebastian", "Jenson", "Daniel"]
for (var i = 0; i < driversNames.length; i++) {
  console.log(driversNames[i] + " " + "is a drivers name");
}

var yourName = prompt("What is your name?")

console.log("Your name is" + " " + yourName)

if (yourName === driversNames) {
  console.log("Awesome" + " " + yourName + " " + "you share the same name as a Formula 1 driver!")
} else {
  console.log("Sorry" + " " + yourName + " " + "you don't have the same name as any Formula 1 drivers")
}
```

Comment: Use `indexOf` to check if array contains given value: `['foo'].indexOf('foo') > (-1)` If value is not in array it will return `-1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a string to an array, so the comparison will return false. You have a few options to fix this though - I'll explain using a loop to check each string, and using `indexOf`.

Loop: You need to loop through each element in the `driversNames` array and compare each one. This is the manual way.

```
var sameName = false; //flag to keep track of if name matches or not
driversNames.forEach(function(name) { //loop through each name in driversNames
    if(yourName === name) { //compare your name to driver name
        sameName = true; //if match, set flag to true
    }
}); //loop ends here
if(sameName) { //if flag is true, a name matched
        console.log("Awesome" + " " + yourName + " " + "you share the same name as a Formula 1 driver!"); //Console log success statement
} else { // else, no name matched
      console.log("Sorry" + " " + yourName + " " + "you don't have the same name as any Formula 1 drivers"); //console log fail statement
}
```

IndexOf: This method uses less lines of code, but isn't compatible on all browsers - I believe anything under IE8 will break when using this for example. But if compatibility isn't an issue, it looks like this:

```
if (driversNames.indexOf(yourName) > -1) { //indexof returns -1 for no match, and a number for match
  console.log("Awesome" + " " + yourName + " " + "you share the same name as a Formula 1 driver!"); //console log success statement
} else {
  console.log("Sorry" + " " + yourName + " " + "you don't have the same name as any Formula 1 drivers"); //console log fail statement
}
```

`indexof` is a little more elegant, although easy to forget the compatibility issue. Code is commented but just to explain it: Arrays have a method you can call, called `indexOf()` which takes a parameter. This method will then check if that parameter is in the array and if it is, return a value which is it's position in the array. If it isn't in the array, it will return `-1`.

Comment: I really appreciate the short and long answer and commented lines to help me understand thanks @millerbr I added indexOf and it did just what I hoped. I'm going to take a look at the browser compatible version too as I'm a sponge right now, anything I can try and understand is going to help me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You made one mistake in this line `if (yourName === driversNames)`. 
It doesnt compare your name with names from `driversNames`. The most easiest way: its use `indexOf` method. So this line should be like below

```
if (driversNames.indexOf(yourName) > -1) //Get Name otherwise no
```

And [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLwd44wy/) example for you, also [indefOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) link

Thanks